In Angular, how to clear the file upload text box after the file is uploaded
HTML
<div class="row">
    <div class="mb-6">
        <label class="form-label" for="defaultFile">Upload file</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="defaultFile" (change)="onChange($event)">
        <hr>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-theme" (click)="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
   </div>
</div>

Typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrl: './file-upload.component.scss'
})
export class FileUploadComponent {
    fileToUpload: File | null = null;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    onChange(event:any) {
        this.fileToUpload = event.target.files[0];
    }

    uploadFile() {
        if (!this.fileToUpload) {
            alert('No file selected.');
            return;
        }

        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);

        return this.http.post("<ENDPOINT TO UPLOAD THE FILE>", formData).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
    }
}


The file upload works fine. Not sure what's the "angular" way to get the text box to clear. (To keep this post simple, I have moved the code that calls API to component and removed all the error handling, etc. to capture the gist.)

To keep it simple, we can use template reference variable #input in html, to pass the element reference into the function and clear the value, using input.value = null
To keep it simple I removed the API calls and replaced them with of(true) to mock and API call!
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mb-6">
            <label class="form-label" for="defaultFile">Upload file</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="defaultFile" (change)="onChange($event)" #input>
            <hr>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-theme" (click)="uploadFile(input)">Upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  fileToUpload: File | null = null;

  constructor() {}

  onChange(event: any) {
    this.fileToUpload = event.target.files[0];
  }

  uploadFile(input: any) {
    if (!this.fileToUpload) {
      alert('No file selected.');
      return;
    }

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);

    return of(true).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        input.value = null; // <- changed here!
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks a lot Naren. Would refering to the textbox also work if the html was not inline

@Sandeep I hope you mean that the html will be in a separate file and referenced using templateUrl, yes it will work!

Thanks a lot Naren. Your answer was very helpful, also many thanks for the efforts you took to create the demo!

if you are using reactive forms you can use this piece of code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
  <div>
    <input type="file" name="test" id="test" [formControl]="test" />
    <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">submit</button>
  </div>
 `,
})
export class TestComponent {
 test: FormControl = new FormControl();

 onSubmit() {
  // submit logic ....

    this.test.reset();
 }
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
